A website displays attachments(files) either as pdf, XMl (XRBL) . I want to see info in XRBL files the same way as i see pdf and not the actual text
A website display attachments(files) as either as pdf , XMl (XRBL) . I want to see info in XRBL files the same way as i see pdf and not the actual. Is there any chrome extension for the same. Ideally I want to click on it and when it open it in browser,some way in the browswer itself  so that I can make sense from it. If not possible in browser then how best to see the contents in a visual format rather than as text.
https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/corporate/xbrl/KANDARP_05042024142508_CLOSURE_TRADING_WINDOW_1081236_05042024022507_WEB.xml

Use a Powershell Script
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$URI = 'https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/corporate/xbrl/KANDARP_05042024142508_CLOSURE_TRADING_WINDOW_1081236_05042024022507_WEB.xml'

$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $URI 

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($Response.Content)
$root = $doc.Root

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($element in $root.Elements())
{
   if($element.Attribute('contextRef') -ne $null)
   {
      $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject

      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Name -NotePropertyValue $element.Name.LocalName
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'Context Ref' -NotePropertyValue $element.Attribute('contextRef').Value
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Value -NotePropertyValue $element.Value
      
      $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
   }
}
$table

Results
Name                                        Context Ref Value
----                                        ----------- -----
NameOfTheCompany                            MainI       Kandarp Digi Smart Bpo Limited
NSESymbol                                   MainI       KANDARP
ScripCode                                   MainI       000000
MSEISymbol                                  MainI       NOTLISTED
ISIN                                        MainI       INE0MOT01016
TypeOfAnnouncementForClosureOfTradingWindow MainI       New
TypeOfEventForClosureOfTradingWindow        MainI       Closure of Trading Window
DateOfStartOfTradingWindowClosure           MainI       2024-04-02
BriefDetailsForTradingWindowClosureEndDate  MainI       Shall be closed till 48 hours after the declaration of finan...
DateOfReport                                MainI       2024-04-05

